# Sudoku terminology

Tags: discussion

The wiki entry for [sudoku](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sudoku) explains some of the basic terminology of a sudoku puzzle, though is far short of being as comprehensive as [Wikipedia's glossary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_Sudoku).

A number of questions come to mind:

1. Are those the only names for the various elements?
2. Are those the "agreed" standard names to be used here on puzzing.SE?
3. Should the wiki entry be made more comprehensive, possibly going as far as including much (or even most?) of Wikipedia's content?